# how to compute the mean of values from different lists

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compute the means of of the first elements in each list, the second elemnts in each list etc and get a list of these means. So i need to get a list d = [5/3, 10/3, ...etc from the following

```
    $
    a = [1,2,2,2,3,4,3]
    b = [2,3,1,9,5,4,6]
    c = [2,5,6,7,8,2,4]
```

can numpy do this in some way?

Comment: What do you mean by the mean of the first element in each list, do you mean the mean of each list? Can you try to reword your question a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question has a numpy tag, I thought I would add a numpy answer too:

```
numpy.mean([a, b, c], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) them together.

```
>>> list(zip((1, 2, 3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3)))
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

From there, you can iterate over the result and take the means as you need them.

Comment: Why not compute the means at the same time, with a comprehension, or by `map`ping the mean function over the lists?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I wasn't trying to provide a complete solution, just get the asker over their problem. I don't know if random access (list comprehension) would be necessary or if one-time sequential access (a generator of some sort) would suffice so I can't really say much more.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without NumPy:

```
>>> map(lambda x: sum(x)/3., zip(a,b,c))
[1.6666666666666667, 3.3333333333333335, 3.0, 6.0, 5.333333333333333, 3.3333333333333335, 4.333333333333333]
```

Comment: Alternately, `map(lambda x, y, z: (x + y + z) / 3, a, b, c)`.